# How to set the fixed box height and hover effect of icon

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can someone advise to me how to set the fixed box height of preview blog post in WP?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="tt-post post-379 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blogovani category-navody category-obsahovy-marketing">
    <a class="tt-post-img custom-hover" href="https://www.nazev-domeny.cz/">
      <img width="392" height="230" src="https://www.nazev-domeny.cz" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="">        </a>
    <div class="tt-post-info">
        <a class="tt-post-title c-h5" href="https://www.nazevdomeny.cz">Praktický návod: Jak správně naformátovat článek</a>
        <div class="tt-post-cat">Zveřejnil</div>
        <div class="simple-text size-3">
          <p>Často se setkávám s&nbsp;tím, že někteří mají problém správně naformátovat článek tak, aby se lépe skenoval. Proč je to dobré?</p>
        </div>
        <a class="c-btn type-4" href="https://www.nazev-domeny.cz">Přečíst</a>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And how to make hover effect of the social icon.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="vc_icon_element vc_icon_element-outer facebook-ikona vc_icon_element-align-center vc_icon_element-have-style">
<div class="vc_icon_element-inner vc_icon_element-color-custom vc_icon_element-have-style-inner vc_icon_element-size-xl vc_icon_element-style-rounded vc_icon_element-background vc_icon_element-background-color-white">
    <span class="vc_icon_element-icon typcn typcn-social-facebook" style="color:#000000 !important"></span><a class="vc_icon_element-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/" title="" target=" _blank"></a></div>
```

Comment: did you tried js?

Comment: why? dont understand you @Gahan